# Some HTML files associated with Dreamweaver template (.dwt) not recognizing jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dreamweaver

I have been tasked with updating the navigation on a site that is using a Dreamweaver template (DWT) as the base file. The navigation was originally built using jQuery navigation UI, however this did not address all of our needs and I have updated it with another version of an accordion.

The .dwt file only is only controlling the navigation and the head of the site.

I have integrated the new xhtml structure and added/removed javascript/jquery into the .dwt file. I saved the file, therefore updating all of the relevant .html files, and verified that the accordion works.

However - the accordion does not work for all of the xhtml files. Some files, seemingly at random, are not pulling in the javascript.

When opening the relevant .html files, I can verify that they have all been updated with the new xhtml and the correct javasctipt. However, when viewing the .html files that are not displaying correctly with FireBug, I can see that none of the jquery/javascript is being applied to the navigation (classes are missing that are injected into the xhtml, but the structure and css is correct).

I've done some research and the only issues I've been able to find are related to .xhtml files not being updated with the correct code, but in my case all of the affected files have the correct xhtml and scripts in the head.

Does anyone have any light to shed on this subject? I am quite puzzled.

Comment: Mmm, difficult to diagnose without seeing a live example. Are you getting any JavaScript errors?

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely certain that the updated files and new versions have been correctly loaded to the live server?  Even if Dreamweaver updates the child files from the .dwt you need to make sure everything is uploaded.